Matrix with lot of columns

This is my code but the 2 last columns are placed in the next line.
\begin{align*}
\textcolor{orange}{J_{h^*}(j(vec(\theta)))}=\textcolor{orange}{J_{a_2}(j(vec(\theta)))}&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial a_2^1}{\partial x_1^1}(j(vec(\theta))) & \cdots &  \frac{\partial a_2^1}{\partial x_1^4}(j(vec(\theta))) &  \frac{\partial a_2^1}{\partial \theta_1^{11}}(j(vec(\theta))) & \cdots &
\frac{\partial a_2^1}{\partial \theta_1^{44}}(j(vec(\theta))) \\
\frac{\partial a_2^2}{\partial x_1^1}(j(vec(\theta))) & \cdots & \frac{\partial a_2^2}{\partial x_1^4}(j(vec(\theta))) & \frac{\partial a_2^2}{\partial \theta_1^{11}}(j(vec(\theta))) & \cdots &
\frac{\partial a_2^2}{\partial \theta_1^{44}}(j(vec(\theta))) \\
\frac{\partial a_2^3}{\partial x_1^1}(j(vec(\theta))) & \cdots &  \frac{\partial a_2^3}{\partial x_1^4}(j(vec(\theta))) &  \frac{\partial a_2^3}{\partial \theta_1^{11}}(j(vec(\theta))) & \cdots &
\frac{\partial a_2^3}{\partial \theta_1^{44}}(j(vec(\theta))) \\
\frac{\partial a_2^4}{\partial x_1^1}(j(vec(\theta))) & \cdots &  \frac{\partial a_2^4}{\partial x_1^4}(j(vec(\theta))) & \frac{\partial a_2^4}{\partial \theta_1^{11}}(j(vec(\theta))) & \cdots &
\frac{\partial a_2^4}{\partial \theta_1^{44}}(j(vec(\theta))) 
\end{pmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\theta_1^{11} & \cdots & \theta_1^{14} & x_1^1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & x_1^{n_s} & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\theta_1^{21} & \cdots & \theta_1^{24} & 0 & x_1^1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & x_1^{n_s} & 0 & 0  \\
\theta_1^{31} & \cdots & \theta_1^{34} & x_1^1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & x_1^{n_s} & 0  \\
\theta_1^{41} & \cdots & \theta_1^{44} & x_1^1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & x_1^{n_s} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}


This is almost surely a \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20} problem. Historically for optimisation reasons, amsthm set this to 10, so you set a higher maximum as needed.

\left( \begin{array}{*{20}c} MyMatrix \end{array} \right) works thanks

Should all instances of vec(\theta) maybe be \vec{\theta}?
